# How do I check the number of move right decimal given variable input?

Tags: javascript, decimal, scale, axis-labels

I am doing an auto scaling for my data for mulitple y-axis based on `yMin` value.

I have a set of input data for multiple yAxis as per below:

`yAxis1:` data set 1 , the `yMin` is `0.118234` --> Hence, my `minScale` for `yAxis1` will be `0.1`

`yAxis2:` data set 2 , the `yMin` is `0.011823` --> Hence, my `minScale` for `yAxis2` will be `0.01`

`yAxis3:` data set 3 , the `yMin` is `0.001182` --> Hence, my `minScale` for `yAxis3` will be `0.001`

Obviously, the `minScale` is depended on the number of `move right decimal` and perform `Math.pow(10, -1*decimal);`

But how could I determine the number of `move right decimal?` Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var decimal = -Math.floor(Math.log(yMin) / Math.log(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

StraightForward Way:

```
var getRightDecimal = function(num) {
    var ori = num;
    var n = 0;
    if(num >= 10) {
        while(num >= 10) {
            --n;
            num /= 10;
        }
    }
    else {
        while(num < 1) {
            ++n;
            num *= 10;
        }
    }
    console.log("yMin:",ori, " Base:",Math.pow(10, -1*n));
    return n;
}
```

### Test

```
getRightDecimal(1.12);
getRightDecimal(10.1);
getRightDecimal(10);
getRightDecimal(100);
getRightDecimal(0.118234);
getRightDecimal(0.011823);
getRightDecimal(0.001182);
```

### Output

```
yMin: 1.12  Base: 1
yMin: 10.1  Base: 10
yMin: 10  Base: 10
yMin: 100  Base: 100
yMin: 0.118234  Base: 0.1
yMin: 0.011823  Base: 0.01
yMin: 0.001182  Base: 0.001
```